# ASP.net image processing and adding this image to Image control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\resim.jpg");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawString(metin, new Font(metin, 9, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 10, 10);
```

With this code I can create a new image. Now I will be showing my image on my web page i.e I will be showing it with Image control. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the modified bitmap as a new file on the server and assign it to the Image control `ImageUrl` property:

```
//after changes were made:
bmp.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/resim_new.jpg"));

//set image control:
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/resim_new.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save it to disk you have to worry about generating a different temp file for each image and cleaning up when your done.  It's probably better to implement an IHttpHandler that generates the image on the fly and writes it back.  Of course you still need to append something to the url so that you know what text to write, but there's no garbage to clean up later.

So you would do something like:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "MyImageHandler.ashx?key=xyz";
```

and you would set up a mapping in your web.config to send requests for MyImageHandler.ashx to your implementing class.